# Removing items nested in JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have some items nested in JSON.

I have the ID of the item I want to delete.

How do I do this? For example, delete John using his ID of 1 using JavaScript

Here is an example of the JSON ;-

```
[  
   [  
      {  
         "ID":1,
         "firstname":"John",
         "surname":"Doe",
         "email":"john.doe@email.com"
      }
   ],
   [  
      {  
         "ID":2,
         "firstname":"Jane",
         "surname":"Doe",
         "email":"jane.doe@email.com"
      }
   ]
]
```

Comment: Why each object inside its own array?

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: What problem are you having? Reading the JSON from wherever (you didn't say) it is stored? Parsing the JSON? Finding the object you want to remove in the array? Deleting that object from the array? Converting the array back to JSON? Saving it back wherever you go it from? As it stands your question is a little unclear and shows a distinct lack of research effort.

Comment: See also [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Yeah, I just rolled-back the edits I made to the question to the OPs original intent based on Quentin's comment.

Comment: JSON means JavaScript Object Notation, so if you're using JavaScript you should just be handling an Object (here it's an Array). Is this the case, and are you having trouble manipulating this Array? Otherwise you want to deserialize your JSON to its native form as soon as possible, no need to handle bloated strings : see `JSON.parse`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create recursive function using reverse `for` loop and when element with same `ID` is found use splice to remove it.

```js
var data = [[{"ID":1,"firstname":"John","surname":"Doe","email":"john.doe@email.com"},{"ID":1,"firstname":"John","surname":"Doe","email":"john.doe@email.com"},[[[{"ID":3,"firstname":"John","surname":"Doe","email":"john.doe@email.com"}]]]],{"ID":1,"firstname":"Jane","surname":"Doe","email":"jane.doe@email.com"},[{"ID":2,"firstname":"Jane","surname":"Doe","email":"jane.doe@email.com"}]]

let findAndDelete = function(data, id) {
  var length = data.length;
  for(var i = length; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(typeof data[i] == 'object') {
      if(data[i].ID == id) data.splice(i, 1);
      if(Array.isArray(data[i])) findAndDelete(data[i], id);
    }
  }
}

findAndDelete(data, 1);
console.log(data)
```

Update: You can also use `filter()` and `find()`

```js
var data = [[{"ID":1,"firstname":"John","surname":"Doe","email":"john.doe@email.com"}],[{"ID":2,"firstname":"Jane","surname":"Doe","email":"jane.doe@email.com"}]]

var result = data.filter(function(e) {
  return !e.find(o => o.ID == 1);
})

console.log(result)
```

.

Comment: This is almost perfect but it leaves an empty array, I need the whole array removing not just the contents

Comment: What if there are other elements in same array?

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear in my question.
If it has that ID the whole entry needs to go.
This removes the data and leaves an empty array inside the object

Answer (score 0):

This will remove objects from your JSON depending on the ID.

```
function removeItem(itemID,jsonStr) {
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
    var compactJsonObj = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; ++i) {
        if (jsonObj[i][0].ID === itemID) {
            delete jsonObj[i];
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; ++i) {
        if (jsonObj[i]) {
            compactJsonObj.push(jsonObj[i]);
        }
    }

    return JSON.stringify(compactJsonObj);
}
```